# setTimeout/clearTimeout for 'timer' event on GTM

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I has been trying to track user engagement on podcasts in a website using custom HTML tag on GTM.
But getting stuck in the tracking for auto-play property.

**Scenario**: a listener is able to auto-play from podcast to podcast. That kinda behavior leads to missing events since as of now, all events (start, play, pause, play next) are triggered by click action

**Problem**: the below code seemingly clears the timeout from the beginning, even when there is no 'click' event happening. I do not wanna declare another setTimeout function after clearTimeout as do not know how long the pause is.

Code:

```
<script>
 
var initial = setTimeout(function(){
  dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'gtm.timer'
  })
  }, 10000);
  
{{Click Element}}.closest('.play-pause-button').addEventListener('click',function(){
  clearTimeout(initial);
  
  })
  
</script>
```

**My idea**: employing timer event.
Specifically, I will set timeout for 'timer' event, after a 80% podcast duration, that event will be pushed into datalayer which simultaneously triggers a tag.
But the challenge is that the listener could pause in the middle of podcast, so I wanna clear timeout every time user clicks on 'play/pause' button to pause.

The timer should only be reset when user clicks on 'play/pause' button to resume his listening.

Could you please help give me some insights?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using `<audio>` tag?  If so you might consider leveraging the `timeupdate` event rather than adding a separate timer.